# Why firebase_admin doesn't resolve when running multiprocesses

Tags: python, firebase, multiprocessing, tornado, firebase-admin

I have a Tornado app which is using python firebase_admin SDK.
When I run in single process:

```
console_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(ConsoleApplication())
console_server.listen(options.console_port, options.bind_addr)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

firebase_admin works fine. But when I change it to run in multiprocess:

```
console_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(ConsoleApplication())
console_server.bind(options.console_port, options.bind_addr)
console_server.start(4)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

The last line here is getting stuck:

```
if (not len(firebase_admin._apps)):
     cred = ...
     self.app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
self.app = firebase_admin.get_app()
self.db = firestore.client()
...
ref = self.db.document(USER_DOC.format(org, value))
user_ref = ref.get()
```

Seems like get() is not getting resolved since I don't get any exception.

Does anyone has an idea why it's happening or at least how can I debug it?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question, but I want to share my experience regarding this issue to help future visitors.

I recently developed a script with `multiprocessing` that uses Firebase Admin Python SDK, everything worked fine in my local Windows machine, but when I deployed it for production in Linux server, I noticed the script is getting stuck in `get()` function.

After hours of searching, I found out that the default start method of a python process is different in Windows and Unix environments: Windows uses `spawn` as default start method, whereas Unix uses `fork`. You can learn more about start methods in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods).

So to make it work in my Linux server, I just changed the start method to `spawn`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn') # <-- Set spawn as start_method
# The rest of your script here
# ...
```

Comment: Awesome how did you find this!

Comment: @njho By following the "read the docs first" rule 

Answer (score 0):

The multiprocess fork (i.e. the `start(4)` call) must come *very early* in the life of your application. In particular, most things that touch the network must come after the fork (`bind()` is one of the few exceptions, and *must* come before the fork in this case).

You (probably) need to reorganize things so that you're creating the firebase app after the fork. This can be annoying if you're using the `HTTPServer.start` method, so you may want to switch to calling `tornado.process.fork_processes()` directly instead (this is documented as the "advanced multi-process" pattern).